# Crystal report : converting date parameter to number of seconds

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I have the following problem.

I have a table column which stores a date time as integer. (number of seconds after `1980-01-01 00:00:00`) For example:

`1980-01-02 00:00:00`  will be stored as  `86400(60*60*24)`
`1980-01-03 00:00:00`  will be stored as `172800`
`1999-12-31 00:00:00`  will be stored as  `" a huge number "`

The problem is, I have created a crystal report where I need to choose a record from the table according to date range.

For this purpose, I have defined a parameter field in crystal report which will provide a date range.Two date picker box to select the date range.

Now What I want to do is , I want to convert each of date value to integer. doing some mathematics. What is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Use datediff with the "s" argument

datediff("s",datetime(1980,1,1,0,0,0),{?yourdateparameter})